# Problem reinstalling. Original install was done while connected to a TV

Tags: installation, tv

I had an old desktop running Win XP connected to my Samsung LED TV with a VGA cable.  It worked fine.  I installed Ubuntu 12.04.  The install went fine.  I could see everything fine on the TV screen.  At the end of the install it does a reboot.  It then came back and said it could not configure itself to the TV screen.

I decided to connect a regular monitor to the computer and do a reinstall.  I turned off the computer, put the 12.04 install DVD in the DVD drive, connected the monitor, and turned the computer back on.

It goes into terminal mode.  It asks for my login and password, then it is at the terminal prompt.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I'm embarrassed by how simple and obvious this was. I had to go into setup and change the boot sequence. The DVD was after the hard drive. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

try typing on the terminal:

```
sudo startx
```

This will help you get back to your Desktop.

If you are planning to re-install Ubuntu just boot from the CD, restart the machine and keep hitting the F12 key for the boot menu and select the CD option and follow the instructions.

**There is a way to change the resolution from unix prompt.